# gmapping pacakage Overlaying with catkin workspaces

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-groovy, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed `ROS groovy` version. I want to do changes in `gmapping`.

Gmapping is using libararies from `openslam_gmapping`, So i have cloned `slam_gmapping` and `openslam_gmapping` separately and built them.

But when i run launch file to run gmapping , i am getting below error

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: can't locate node [slam_gmapping] in package [gmapping]
```

**launch file :**

```
<launch> <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" respawn="false" output="screen">   
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="map_update_interval" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="maxUrange" value="69"/>
  <param name="maxRange" value="71"/>
  <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
  <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
  <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
  <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
  <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
  <param name="srr" value="0.01"/>
  <param name="srt" value="0.02"/>
  <param name="str" value="0.01"/>
  <param name="stt" value="0.02"/>
  <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.3"/>
  <param name="temporalUpdate" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="resampleThreshold" value="5"/>
  <param name="particles" value="10"/>
  <param name="xmin" value="-5.0"/>
  <param name="ymin" value="-5.0"/>
  <param name="xmax" value="5.0"/>
  <param name="ymax" value="5.0"/>
  <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
  <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
  <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
  <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
  <remap from="scan" to="laserscan"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

How to do code changes to `openslam_gmapping`

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120771/gmapping-pacakage-overlaying-with-catkin-workspaces/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-01-22**:
Do you mean with "but it was from ros stack not the package which i cloned,did changes and built." that a copy of gmapping you installed with apt-get is being executed and not the copy you cloned from source?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-23**:
@BennyRe yes

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-23**:
If you get the error above I'm pretty sure you have NOT built it. Also IIRC the gmapping package does download gmapping itself during the build process.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-23**:
@dornhege i have cloned and build the slam_gmapping  cloned from https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping.git

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-01-23**:
Did you correctly overlay these two packages? Here's the tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-23**:
@BennyRe i followed as tutorial i was able to buid and roscd is working fine but when i run from "roslaunch gmapping slam_gmapping_pr2.launch" i am getting error as mentioned in question.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-01-23**:
Does your binary exist? check /devel/lib/gmapping

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-23**:
@BennyRe yes binary exists in /home/overlay_ws/slam_gmapping/devel/lib/gmapping

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-01-23**:
Did you source the overlay_ws in the terminal yor using to roslaunch?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-23**:
@BennyRe yes i add line "source overlay_ws/slam_gmapping/devel/setup.bash" to .bashrc

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-23**:
@BennyRe i did source devel/setup.bash in terminal, after that  i was able to launch gmapping but i am not able to launch my packages.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-24**:
Are they included in the same workspace?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-24**:
@dornhege No they both are in different work spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have two different workspaces sourcing either one will replace the other fully.

If you want both together you can either merge all packages in one workspace or [overlay](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) one workspace with another.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-24**:
Thanks, it worked after putting slam_gmapping, openslam_gmapping in mypackage/src/ and overlay mypackage.

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2014-01-29**:
bvb,
I want to do the same thing you are, but I am uncertain how to get setup the openslam_gmapping sources so they build and are recognized as a ROS package.  will the "find_packag(catkin REQUIRED nav_msgs openslam_gmapping roscpp rostest tf)"in CMakeLists.txt just work?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-29**:
@gershon i did git clone for gmapping and openslam_gmapping inside /src folder of my package. This tutorial is helpful.http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2014-01-29**:
Aha!  I see now.  The only link to source from the slam_gmapping page takes me to an external site that lists the code in a svn repository.  Now I think I see what you mean.  I did find the openslam_gmapping source on git.  Thanks!

**Comment by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) on 2015-05-14**:
@bvbdort Can you please provide some clarification?  I am having the same problem, and the Workspace  Overlay Tutorial isn't helping me.  Thanks!

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2015-05-15**:
@davidgitz can you tell me what is the exact problem.

**Comment by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) on 2015-05-18**:
@bvbdort
I don't want to hijack this thread but I think my problem is identical.  I have done a git clone for the slam_gmapping and openslam_gmapping and put in: ~/catkin_ws/src  Then I did: source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash and  source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash and get the same error as the OP.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2015-05-18**:
your procedure is correct, did you build, if yes check binaries in catkin_ws/devel/lib

**Comment by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) on 2015-05-19**:
I had not built it.  I had to install the following packages:libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-image-gst yaml-cpp along with cloning the navigation stack.  After that I got it to work.  Thanks!